# W3C validation of Dreamweaver HTML

Tags: html

I have an errant '>'appearing mysteriously on one of my pages.  I went to the W3C validation page and they found a boatload of errors.  But all the errors are in code generated by Dreamweaver CS 5.5. They found 14 errors/warnings in the middle line alone.

```
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
   var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
 }
```

I'm new and to be honest I don't understand this code yet.  I'm pretty sure it's part of my roll over button menu.  Is this really something I need to worry about or are they overly strict?

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie.

Comment: Are you validating XHTML?

Comment: That wouldn't be an error if it wasn't XHTML. Don't use XHTML, it is more trouble then it is worth. (For that matter, don't use Dreamweaver's JavaScript, it is awful).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the HTML Dreamweaver generates is considered by many to be poor in comparison to what you would hand write – that JS example is a good example – you wouldn't do that in JS normally, but in CSS, where it is a lot simpler.

Comment: I'll concur with the above statements, don't autogenerate code with Dreamweaver (or anything else for that matter) and expect it to pass any form of online validation.

Comment: @Quentin I would go further and say just don't use dreamweaver, it's awful!

Comment: Gentleman, thank you all very much for your help.  Unfortunately I barely know HTML and am just scratching the surface of PHP and MySQL.  I'm reading and learning but trying to get into JavaScript at this point is just not an issue.  This old mind can only absorb so much. [Grin]  I'd be in trouble without Dreamweaver but as I remember none of the pros, such as yourselves, liked Front Page at all.  A huge learning curve but I'll get there in time... I hope.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, use the following process to easily find and fix mismatched tags:

- Download [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)
- Configure [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html)
- Run it